# How to force WebStorm to show file paths in "Recent Files" dialog

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

`⌘E` shortcut (`View | Recent Files`) shows the list of the most recent files.
If you take a look into the screenshot below you would see that it is not possible to use this feature as there is no context for the files provided.
Is there a way to configure WebStorm so it shows a part of the path before the file name (like IntelliJ IDEA does it)?

**WebStorm:**

[image]

**IntelliJ IDEA:**

[image]

Comment: this is a platform-wide functionality and, to me, webstorm behaves just in the same way as IDEA: only file names are shown... related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169665

Comment: @lena interesting, but I'm pretty sure I do not have all those files open in IntelliJ IDEA and it still manages to prefix file names with the parent directory name.